# After clicking buttons action attribute is switching n if mistakenly clicked on wrong button i have to refresh the page otherwise route won't switch

Tags: javascript, html, forms, attributes, action

i have a form, inside this form i have "local" "airport" "oneway" "roundtrip" buttons.
i have written an javascript code, which will set action attribute according to which button is clicked but the problem is when i mistakenly clicked on wrong button and then click on correct button the action attribute is not switching to the correct button route but to switch the correct route in the action attribute **i have to refresh the page.**
i want to change the action attribute value without refreshing the page.

[here is the image of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1nnV.png)

here is my javascript code:-

`````
        var addInputBtn = document.getElementById("addInputBtn");
        var myform = document.getElementById("cabform");
        var clicked = false;
        addInputBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
                if (!clicked) {
                    myform.setAttribute("action", "/airport");
                    clicked = true;
                }
                
        });

        var localBtn = document.getElementById("localBtn");
        localBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
                if (!clicked) {
                    myform.setAttribute("action", "/local");
                    clicked = true;
                }
        });

        var oneWay = document.getElementById("oneWay");
        oneWay.addEventListener("click", function(){
                if (!clicked) {
                    myform.setAttribute("action", "/oneway");
                    clicked = true;
                }
        });

        var roundTrip = document.getElementById("roundTrip");
        roundTrip.addEventListener("click", function(){
                if (!clicked) {
                    myform.setAttribute("action", "/roundtrip");
                    clicked = true;
                }
        });

        var searchcab = document.getElementById("searchcab");
        var paragraphId = document.getElementById("pid");
        searchcab.addEventListener("click", function(){
            if (!clicked) {
                paragraphId.innerHTML = "Please select one of the Button: Airport, local"
                searchcab.setAttribute("type", "button");
            } else if (clicked) {
                searchcab.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            }
        });
    </script>````

Any suggestion, any help would be great thanks

i am trying to setting the action attribute when a user click on a button, problem is i have to do refresh the page to select the another button otherwise it redirect to the wrong route
`````

Answer (score 0):

if you want this behavior  then simply remove your if-condition. once u click on the element, you set `clicked` to `true` meaning your `action` attribute can never update until you refresh, because `clicked` is `false` by default.